# Looking for the repository and documentation for this undo script

Tags: javascript, jquery, undo

I have found this chart: http://jsperf.com/undo-redo and saw the results. 
But which history script does he mean? Seems this is the fastest and possibly the best? Where can I find it?

Seems this is the only script?:
https://gist.github.com/NoxArt/2692147/raw/3351cd3749bcacf684795580873c3a542e68854b/gistfile1.coffee

Is there somewhere a repository for this history script or the full documentation

Comment: Per the flagging menu: _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: I know. But I just found this: https://gist.github.com/NoxArt/2692147/raw/3351cd3749bcacf684795580873c3a542e68854b/gistfile1.coffee but not a complete library or the script on GitHub with the documentation, is this the only script and no documentation or repository?

Comment: I have changed my question as I am currently just looking for the history script and some documentation for it. Or was this only written for the jsperf test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

The link you posted is the library you are looking for. But it's written in [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/). If you [transpile](http://js2coffee.org/) it into Javascript, you will get exactly the class used in the test (and that I posted below).

---

I'm not sure if I'm just missing the point, but the entire code of all used libraries is stored in the "Preparation Code" section (how else would jsperf know what to execute). The `History` library in particular is

```
/**
   Class managing undo/redo
   @constructor
   */
var History = (function () {

    /**
     Properties
     @actions [{name(string), identifier(string), undo(callback), redo(callback)}]
     @current pointer to a current point in history list, all the lower is history and all the higher ones are future

     @param config {Object}
     */

    function History(config) {
        this.config = {
            limit: Infinity,
            onUndo: function () {},
            onRedo: function () {},
            onChange: function () {}
        };
        for (var i in config) this.config[i] = config[i];

        this.actions = [];
        this.current = -1;
    }


    /**
     Stores the action that happened and it's undo callback
     Caller must ensure undo and redo callbacks turn the model into a proper state

     @param {String} name
     @param {Function} actionDo - callback describing what's happened, serves as a 'redo' callback
     @param {Function} actionUndo
     @optionalParam {String} identifier - identifier, for example name of the mark that has been just added
     */
    History.prototype.happened = function (name, actionDo, actionUndo, id) {
        this.clearFuture();
        this.actions.push({
            name: name,
            identifier: id || "",
            undo: actionUndo,
            redo: actionDo
        });
        this.current++;
        this.config.onChange.call(this, "happened", this.actions.length);
        if (this.config.limit !== Infinity) {
            while (this.actions.length > this.config.limit) {
                this.actions.shift();
                this.current--;
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     Triggers a given action and stores it as redo

     Caller must ensure undo and redo callbacks turn the model into a proper state

     @param {String} name
     @param {Function} actionDo - callback describing should now happen, serves also as a 'redo' callback
     @param {Function} actionUndo
     @optionalParam {String} id - identifier, for example name of the mark that has been just added
     */
    History.prototype.happen = function (name, actionDo, actionUndo, id) {
        this.happened(name, actionDo, actionUndo, id || "");
        return actionDo();
    };

    /**
     Undos X steps

     @optionalParam {Number} steps
     */
    History.prototype.undo = function (steps) {
        var self = this,
            step = 0;

        steps = steps || 0;
        if (steps === 0) return this.undoOne();

        while (step++ < steps) {
            self.undoOne();
            self.config.onUndo();
            self.config.onChange.call(self, "undo", self.current + 1);
        }
    };

    History.prototype.undoOne = function () {
        if (this.actions[this.current]) {
            this.actions[this.current].undo();
            this.config.onChange.call(this, "undo", this.current);
            return this.current--;
        }
    };

    /**
     Redos X steps

     @optionalParam {Number} steps
     */
    History.prototype.redo = function (steps) {
        var self = this,
            step = 0;

        steps = steps || 0;

        if (steps === 0) return this.redoOne();

        while (step++ < steps) {
            self.redoOne();
            self.config.onRedo();
            self.config.onChange.call(this, "redo", self.current + 1);
        }
    };

    History.prototype.redoOne = function () {
        if (this.actions[this.current + 1]) {
            this.current++;
            this.config.onChange.call(this, "redo", this.current + 1);
            return this.actions[this.current].redo();
        }
    };

    History.prototype.goTo = function (val) {
        return this.actions[val];
    };


    /**
     Returns all entries that can be undo-ed

     @return [historyStack]
     */
    History.prototype.getHistory = function () {
        if (this.current === -1) {
            return [];
        } else {
            return this.actions.slice(0, this.current + 1);
        }
    };


    /**
     Returns all entries that can be redo-ed

     @return [historyStack]
     */
    History.prototype.getFuture = function () {
        if (this.current + 1 >= this.actions.length) {
            return [];
        } else {
            return this.actions.slice(this.current + 1, this.actions.length);
        }
    };



    /**
     Has history entries = can undo?

     @returns bool
     */
    History.prototype.hasHistory = function () {
        return this.current > -1;
    };


    /**
     Has future entries = can redo?

     @returns bool
     */
    History.prototype.hasFuture = function () {
        return this.current + 1 < this.actions.length;
    };

    /**
     Clear the complete history stack

     @returns [historyStack]
     */
    History.prototype.clear = function () {
        this.current = -1;
        this.actions = [];
    };

    History.prototype.clearFuture = function () {
        if (this.current + 1 < this.actions.length) {
            this.actions.splice(this.current + 1, this.actions.length - this.current - 1);
            return History;
        }
    };

    return History;

})();
```

The test setup (= usage) is also in there

```
var history = new History();
var historyTotal = 0;

function historyTest() {
    history.happen("toggle", function () {
        historyTotal++;
    }, function () {
        historyTotal--;
    });
}

historyTest();
historyTest();
historyTest();
history.undo();
history.undo();
history.redo();
history.undo();
history.redo();
```

However, it doesn't say where this is coming from or who wrote it, so the licensing is unclear, too.

Comment: hm, this is not good because I need the documentation and the license too

Comment: Do you really need to be able to perform 300,000 undos per second? That sounds insane. Just go with another library.

Comment: Although you could try to contact the author of the jsperf test, since he should know where he got that library from. Here's his github profile: https://github.com/yckart

Comment: I know that this is not allowed, but which library would you suggest?

Comment: You know. I just now notice the link to the coffeescript you posted. That one **is** the `History` script. But it's coffeescript, so it needs to be transpiled into Javascript. Which means you have already found the source of the script including the author.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. By the way, the script is simple enough to understand it without lengthy documentation. Plus it is documented with JSDoc.

Comment: Are you sure that this script is from the Github user Yckart? https://gist.github.com/NoxArt/2692147#comments Not NoxArt?

Comment: No, I said yckart is the author of the **jsperf test** and you could contact him to find out where he got that script from. However, this isn't necessary anymore since you actually already found the source of the script – only that you found the original Coffeescript version.